# Split string by last "/" and capture both sections of split - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, split

I have the following ruby code which splits a string by each `'/'`, assigns each split to a variable, inserts another string immediately after the last `'/'` and then rejoins all of them whilst assigning them to a variable.

```
    object = "uploads/video/screenshot/74/DGSCFUA_video.jpg"
    up, vid, pic, num, file = object.split('/')
    file = "#{up}/#{vid}/#{pic}/#{num}/#{file.insert(0, "mini_")}"
    p file

    >> "uploads/video/screenshot/74/mini_DGSCFUA_video.jpg"
```

Whilst this works, it feels like I'm missing a trick and this isn't the most efficient way of doing things.

Is it possible to split a string at the last `'/'`, `(i.e. object.split('/')[-1])` but capture both parts of the split rather than just the characters after the `'/'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're massaging a filepath, so use tools made for that task:

```
path_to_file = "uploads/video/screenshot/74/DGSCFUA_video.jpg"

file_path, file_name = File.split(path_to_file) 
# => ["uploads/video/screenshot/74", "DGSCFUA_video.jpg"]
```

Alternately, you can split like this:

```
file_path, file_name = File.dirname(path_to_file), File.basename(path_to_file) 
# => ["uploads/video/screenshot/74", "DGSCFUA_video.jpg"]
```

Then build the new path using:

```
path_to_file = File.join(file_path, "mini_#{ file_name }") 
# => "uploads/video/screenshot/74/mini_DGSCFUA_video.jpg"
```

The advantage is, Ruby's [IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html) class, which is File's ancestor, takes the OS into account when it determines the path separators, so it will do the right thing if the code is running on Windows or *nix.

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb". When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the backslashes:
>
> ```
> "c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"
> ```

Comment: THIS is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would go this way -

```
str = "uploads/video/screenshot/74/DGSCFUA_video.jpg"
ar = File.split(str) # => ["uploads/video/screenshot/74", "DGSCFUA_video.jpg"]
ar[-1] = ar[-1].prepend("mini_")
File.join(*ar)
# => "uploads/video/screenshot/74/mini_DGSCFUA_video.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks for these babai! Any reason why a regex is preferred?

Comment: @dodgerogers747 I just tried to show what other ways we could get `"uploads/video/screenshot/74/mini_DGSCFUA_video.jpg"` . But if you want this `["uploads/video/screenshot/74", "DGSCFUA_video.jpg"]` only then `File#split` most preferable for me.. :) Now your choice..

Answer (score 1):

A regexp could be more flexible and more reusable:

```
 s = 'uploads/video/screenshot/74/DGSCFUA_video.jpg'
 s.scan(/(.*)\/(.*)/)
 => [["uploads/video/screenshot/74", "DGSCFUA_video.jpg"]]
```